# Problem with algorithmicx: perhaps a missing \item. What's wrong?

Tags: algorithmicx

I'm trying to write simple pseudocodes using package `algorithmicx` in TexWorks 0.4.4 and MiKTex 2.9 on Windows 7 but I get this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.39  \State
             $sum\gets 0$
```

My document is pasted below, what's wrong with it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algpascal}
\usepackage{algc}
\usepackage{algcompatible}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}

\title{Pseudocódigos}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{Introdução}

\section{Pilha}

\subsection{Empilhar}

Oia.

Just testing

\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure {Termial}{$n$}
 \State $sum\gets 0$
 \State $i\gets 1$
 \While{i\le n}
   \State $sum\gets sum+i$
   \State $i\gets i+1$
\EndWhile
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\subsection{Desempilhar}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some investigative work, I found that,

- loading `algpseudocode` after `algcompatible`, and
- adding inline-math delimiters (`$`) that are missing in your `\While`,

solves the problem; your input file now compiles without mishap (for me, anyway).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpascal}
\usepackage{algc}
\usepackage{algcompatible}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}

\title{Pseudocódigos}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section{Introdução}
\section{Pilha}
\subsection{Empilhar}

Oia. Just testing

\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure {Termial}{$n$}
 \State $sum\gets 0$
 \State $i\gets 1$
 \While{$i\le n$}
   \State $sum\gets sum+i$
   \State $i\gets i+1$
\EndWhile
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\subsection{Desempilhar}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 One day that error message will be generated by a missing `\item`. One day, perhaps.

Comment: Wow, that's crazy. Took me hours and turned out I just need to relocate `algpseudocode`