# standalone problem with algorithmicx, algorithm, algpseudocode packages. perhaps a missing \item

Tags: standalone, algorithmicx, algorithmic, algpseudocode

I am using the code from [How may I remove \EndIf and \EndFor in algorithmicx?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145760/how-may-i-remove-endif-and-endfor-in-algorithmicx)

The code, as is, works in article class. But in standalone it fails. I searched and found one needs to add `[H]` to `algorithm` when using standalone. Reference: [standalone document with algorithm2e package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/617233/standalone-document-with-algorithm2e-package)

> However, if you give the algorithm the [H] option, it will no longer
> be floating, so you can use it.

But that did not fix the problem.

Here is the code I am using

```
\documentclass[10pt,crop]{standalone}  %error
%\documentclass[10pt]{article}  %works
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algorithm} % http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode} % http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{A}{}
    \ForAll{$a\in A$}
        \If{$a\geq b$}
            \State\Return $a$
        \EndIf
    \EndFor
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Compiling with lualatex gives

```
(./first_order_series.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.10 \begin{algorithm}
                    [H]
?
```

Removing the `[H]` makes no difference.   Compiling with article class, it works, no error

[image]

I wanted to use `standalone` to make a single pdf file which I can include as an image in the main document.

I also tried the workaround given in  [Problem with algorithmicx: perhaps a missing \item. What's wrong?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119047/problem-with-algorithmicx-perhaps-a-missing-item-whats-wrong)

> loading algpseudocode after algcompatible,

But it made no effect. The error is still there only when using standalone.

Is there a workaround?

TL 2022

**Update**

Here is a much simpler MWE which shows an error using `algorithmic` package

```
\documentclass[10pt,crop]{standalone}  %error
%\documentclass[10pt]{article}  %works
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[H]
\STATE $i\gets 10$
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

lualatex gives

```
(./first_order_series.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.9 \STATE
         $i\gets 10$
?
```

It looks like standalone is not compatible with all these algorithm packages?

Comment: For your very last code block: try with `\documentclass[10pt,crop,varwidth]{standalone} `

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz wow! that fixed everything (adding varwidth). If you like to make this answer will be happy to accept it.

Comment: There is no need to load `algorithmicx`, since it should be loaded by your choice of language/style when loading `algpseudocode`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use floats with standalone, but these are all vertical display environments so can not be used in a horizontal box like `\mbox` which is essentially what `standalone` provides. If you use the `varwidth` option it instead uses a `\parbox` so that you can use display material, and uses the `varwidth` package to choose a suitable width.

```
\documentclass[10pt,crop,varwidth]{standalone}  %error
%\documentclass[10pt]{article}  %works
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algorithm} % http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode} % http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{A}{}
    \ForAll{$a\in A$}
        \If{$a\geq b$}
            \State\Return $a$
        \EndIf
    \EndFor
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

[image]